# Is it Possible to do a private chat with Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

I want to do a one to one private chat with Django-channels, but i cant find any article/post about it, all i see is on creating group chat.

It seem to me like Django-channel can only be used in creating group chat and group gaming system.
I want to know if django-channels can handle a one to one private chat and how do i go about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familair with `django-channel` but reading through the tutorial it seems to me that you can manage channels and their privacy using models and permissions.

```
class OneOnOneRoom(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name = 'user1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name = 'user2')
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique=True)
```

Then for your view (this is a modification of the example in the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html)

```
def room(request, room_name):
    if not OneOnOneRoom.objects.filter(room_name=room_name).exists():
        OneOnOneRoom.objects.create(...)#create the room with the users information forwarded with your request 
    room = OneOnOneRoom.objects.get(room_name=room_name)
    if request.User != room.user1 and request.User != room.user2:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest() #or deny permission some other way
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        
        'room_name_json': mark_safe(json.dumps(room_name))
    })
```

When a user tries to join a channel, reject the view.

**NOTE**:

I'm not sure is that is the exact way you should compare users, but it should convey the idea

Comment: This is similar to what i want but if a user wants to create a conversation it will reject this user.

Comment: Edited the answer to create a room in case it does not exist, you will need to pass in some info in your request or url @Starbody

Comment: Ok, if i get you correctly every conversation creates a room for the two parties who want to chat?

Comment: Yeah, unless it exists then they just join it instead of creating a new one

Comment: i'm using django jwt rest framework will it still work, i mean the authentication

Comment: ```if request.User != room.user1 or request.User != room.user2:``` that ```or``` should be an ```and```

Answer (score 0):

I, too, had a hard time finding information about this and ended up buying a course that does it like @robotHamster suggests,but I didn't find that solution elegant.

What you can do is send messages directly to other channels, instead of other groups (and let the group send to all channels in it).

More information here:
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#synchronous-functions

Basically, instead of using `channel_layer.group_send`, you'll use `channel_layer.send`.